# Featured Images not getting uploaded?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

when i click to upload a featured image for any post or page it gives me this error:

```
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

and also images display in the media section when i click on the featured image link . i have tried many thing changed permissions of the uploads folder made them writable by setting permissions to

```
0777
```

and activated and deactivated all the plugins but still its giving me this error . Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

when i click on the set featured image the images in Media Library also don't show up instead it shows like this :
[image]

i have pictures in my media library but they don't show up there..

[image]

or it has something to do with the uploads path ?

Comment: there must be image dimension issue or image issue, try uploading proper image with less then 2MB size of image. also look the guide here and edit your question with the help of screenshots :) try this link , [click here](https://sebastian.expert/fix-wordpress-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again-later/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved:
there was some malware in my wordPress i have downloaded a new copy of wordpress and then installed my theme in it and it works fine now ...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Your all active plugins. Deactive all plugins in your theme.And then try to upload image then media is working. After media working then one by one active your plugins. Then check out your plugin which give error to upload file.